# no security manager: RMI class loader disabled

Tags: java, classloader, rmi

i like to call RMI,but the Exception is throwed.what's wrong with it?

> Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error
>   unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Hello (no security manager:
>   RMI class loader disabled)    at
>   sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.xx.rmiproxy.RmiProxy.call(RmiProxy.java:39)   at
>   com.xx.rmiproxy.RmiProxy.main(RmiProxy.java:18) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Hello (no security manager: RMI
>   class loader disabled)    at
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadProxyClass(Unknown Source)

```
public String call(String rmiId, String json) throws Exception{

    RmiInterfaceDescription desc = dao.getDescriptionById(rmiId);
    desc.setJarFile("d:\\test.jar");

    RmiClientClassLoader rmiClassLoader = new RmiClientClassLoader(null,desc);

    Class interfaceClass = rmiClassLoader.loadClass(desc.getInterfaceName());
    List<String> paraClasses = desc.getParaClasses();

    Class returnClass = rmiClassLoader.loadClass(desc.getReturnClass());

    Object obj = Naming.lookup(desc.getRmiUrl());

    Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[paraClasses.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<paraClasses.size();i++){
        parameterTypes[i]= rmiClassLoader.loadClass(paraClasses.get(i));
    }

    Method method = interfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod(desc.getMethodName(),
            parameterTypes);

    Object params[] = parseParamsFromJson();
    Object result = method.invoke(obj, "ssd");


    return encode(result);
}
```

.....

```
public class RmiClientClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    RmiInterfaceDescription description = new RmiInterfaceDescription();

    description.setJarFile("d:\\test.jar");
    RmiClientClassLoader cl = new RmiClientClassLoader(null, description);

    Class clientClass = cl.loadClass("test.client.HelloClient");
}

private String basedir;
private RmiInterfaceDescription description;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public RmiClientClassLoader(String basedir,
        RmiInterfaceDescription description) throws MalformedURLException {
    super(new URL[] { new File(description.getJarFile()).toURL() });
    this.basedir = basedir;
    this.description = description;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong thing. The important part of this exception is the ClassNotFoundException and the class it names. Whatever class that is need to be deployed at the client, and available to the Registry if you're running it as a separate process.

I don't know why you're defining your own class loader. The codebase feature is generally sufficient.

Comment: I need this feature,other software system's manager can upload there rmi client jar files and define their rmi interface.

Comment: then can call their customized rmi.Is codebase suituable for this feature?

Comment: I've already answered that. 'The codebase feature is generally sufficient'.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Registry lookup ,because of security issues  the Client need the (Remote ) interface with the same full package name as it is defined in the stub handler class.
simply put the remote interface in the same full package name in the definition, client and server place .